# Edit user form with roles

Tags: php, symfony, user-roles

I am trying to make an new/edit user form with role selection.
I managed to make the login but I am struggling to figure out how to make the **role dropdown** work.
(**roles** table have 2 entries: ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER)
My entity configuration is:

```
Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    repositoryClass: Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    manyToMany:
       roles:
         targetEntity: Role
         joinTable:
           name: user_role
           joinColumns:
             user_id:
               referencedColumnName: id
           inverseJoinColumns:
             role_id:
               referencedColumnName: id
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

        user_name:
            type: string
            length: '40'

        user_surname:
            type: string
            length: '40'

        password:
            type: integer
            length: '6'

        salt:
            type: string
            length: '32'

        user_created:
            type: datetime
            columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }

Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\Role:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\RoleRepository
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        name:
            type: string
            length: '30'
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

My User(trimmed) entity:

```
/**
     * Add roles
     *
     * @param \Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\Role $roles
     * @return User
     */
    public function addRole(\Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles[] = $roles;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Remove roles
     *
     * @param \Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\Role $roles
     */
    public function removeRole(\Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
    }

    /**
     * Get roles
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }
    public function getRolesForm()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }
    public function setRolesForm($role)
    {
        return $this->roles[]=$role;
    }
     /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }
```

Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user_name')
            ->add('user_surname')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('roles')
        ;
        $builder->add('save', 'submit');
    }
```

I have tried with rolesForm, as indicated in other threads:

```
 $builder
        ->add('user_name')
        ->add('user_surname')
        ->add('password')
        ->add('rolesForm')
    ;
```

But I only get an empty input, searched but can`t figure it out ... any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Role** is an entity, so you could use the [*Entity* field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

```
    $builder
        ->add('user_name')
        ->add('user_surname')
        ->add('password')
        ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Service\SafetyBundle\Entity\Role',
            'property' => 'name',
        ));
    ;
```

This will add all of your available roles in the DB to the field. You can also set the `choices` option to something like `$user->getRoles()` to use that list, or [use a QueryBuilder instance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) to filter the available roles.

Comment: This indeed pupulates my dropdown! thank you but on edit when I change the name for instance it will try to insert the role again in table: user_role

Comment: What do you mean with "it will try to insert the role again"? I don't think that's supposed to happen automatically? Maybe you save the _Role_ entity somewhere in your controller?

Comment: On edit it will try to insert the relation between user and role again, i will try to do it in the controller but not with $form->getData();